# linear algebra done right problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I came up with a different proof of the problem, but my proof and the solution both assume the V is finite dimensional even though it is not given in the problem.

Just wondering if it is something I can assume or there is someway to prove it?

Comment: At the beginning of the set of exercises, does it say something like "Throughout these exercises, assume $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, unless the contrary is explicitly stated"?

Comment: I couldn't find any. It is from linear algebra done right 3rd edition 3.B #24 if that helps.

Comment: Would I be right in surmising that "linear algebra done right" means the textbook by that title, by Sheldon Axler?  (In which case you'd be expected to avoid using determinants.) $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, it is the book by Axler.

Comment: Even in Axler's proof, he assumes that $V$ is finite-dimensional. Look at the statement "then it can be extended to a basis ... of $V$"

Comment: I suspect that the statement still holds when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.  Certainly the proof of the "if" part still works in that case.

Comment: @Bye_World: I suspected that too, and I tried to proof the case when V is infinite dimensional. But since W is finite dimensional, null T1 and null T2 have to be infinite dimensional. Then I have an infinite sequence being a subset of another infinite sequence. And I am not sure how many of the theorems I've learned are still valid in infinite dimension.

Comment: This problem is indeed from my book. However, the proof given by the proposer is not due to me (I make this comment because a previous comment incorrectly refers to it as "Axler's proof"). The problem as stated above is correct. Assume that $W$ is finite-dimensional. But there is no assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional, and no results about infinite-dimensional vector spaces are needed for a solution.

Comment: @Harry the proof of amdyes below (after updating it to extend $S$ to all of $W$) never requires that $W$ be finite dimensional, ***except*** for the part where he will chooses a basis, and further when he extends that basis, and that's only if you want to avoid the axiom of choice, which says every basis of a subspace can be extended to a basis of the whole space.  No infinite sums need ever be taken in this context.  So the proof does carry over to the general case with the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$:

$\mathrm{range} T$ is finite-dimensional with a basis $T_1 v_1,\ldots,T_1 v_n$.

Define $S T_1 v_i = T_2 v_i$.

For any $v \in V$,

\begin{array}{rcl}
     T_1 v \in \mathrm{range} T_1 & \Rightarrow & T_1 v = a_1 T_1 v_1 + \cdots +
     a_n T_1 v_n\\
     & \Rightarrow & T_1 v = T_1  (a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n)\\
     & \Rightarrow & T_1  (v - (a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n)) = 0\\
     \mathrm{null} T_1 \subseteq \mathrm{null} T_2 & \Rightarrow & T_2  (v - (a_1
     v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n)) = 0\\
     & \Rightarrow & T_2 v = T_2  (a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n)\\
     S T_1 v & = & a_1 S T_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n S T_1 v_n\\
     & = & T_2  (a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n)\\
     & = & T_2 v
   \end{array}

Comment: You have only defined $S$ on the range of $T$.  You need to extend $S$ to all of $W$, which you can do by extending the basis to all of $W$ and defining $S$ to vanish on the additional basis members.